# Find value from input tag and change it

Tags: javascript, html, web, firefox

TL;DR: I want to change every input tag with value="NaNaNaNaNaNaNaNaNaNaNaNaNaNaNaN" to a empty string.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg97Q.jpg)

Background: I have a problem with a new tool from eBay. Is supposed to show my listings to copy on their other domains but for some reason they added to each of my listings in the EAN field a string and throws an error. I contacted them and their response was something along the lines of: *Yep, is an error on our side. Change that field manually.* Less funny when that means doing it ~2000 times.
I'm not a web developer so my javascript to use in the Firefox console is not that good.

Comment: Do you have the data of EAN as a JSON, CSV, etc?

Comment: The EAN code should be empty as when I created the listing. I don't have any for them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a very weird problem to me. Also because it wasn't caused by you in any way. What I would try if I were you is pasting something like this into the console to clear all input fields that include the text `NaN`.

```
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach((input) =>
    input.value.includes('NaN') && (input.value = ''));
```

Comment: Oh didn't work. As son I click on try again the field is replaced with "NaNa..." again.